# Mobile application getting error due to long time taking HTTP response

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, blackberry

I am working on a mobile native application in Blackberry WebWorks. My application runs on Tomcat 5.5 which fetches data from an ASMX webservice running on IIS 7.5.

I am getting a timeout after a period of 2 mins during data-fetching operation. I can not over come this problem please help me to overcome.

I am setting the ajax timeout and in the config file I have also mentioned the timeout, still I am getting the timeout.

After a long research I found out that the problem lies with the ASMX service call. In a particular ASMX service method, the method is taking on an average of 4 mins to respond with the result due to involvement of a huge calculation. As the HTTP response is not coming back for a long time the calling application is getting timeout, my ASMX webservice is working properly.

I tried everything with server.xml file of Tomcat 5.5, included all the properties possible to overcome this but with no result.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: If you're going to do this, then you need to look into leveraging `node.js` and `socket.io` so you can `push the response back to the client` without `keeping one HTTPD thread open`.

Comment: Did you look at the memory logs to see if Java is running out of memory? This happens. All. The. Time.

Comment: thanks Ohgodwhy. Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: [http://socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Ohgodwhy, please give me details how can i use socket.io to solve my problem

Comment: @ohgodwhy, I'm not seeing any connection to node.js in this question.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue - The whole idea seems to be to eliminate the connection timeout between the client and the server, and let the server respond when it's done. I've never used either socket.io or node.js, so who knows the details of whether it would work or how it would be setup (with Java also *it's* client). This type of thing is what node.js and socket.io are supposed to excel at, though, so it at least appears as if Ohgodwhy had a point, however potentially unrealistic or unlikely it may be.

Comment: Right Jared Farrish !! in my understanding too I feel that we need to eliminate the time out between the client & server(where the tomcat app is running). Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell us more about the "huge calculation" to get specific help. There are a few strategies that can be applied, depending on the nature of the calculation:

1. If the client is sending a large workload, break it up into smaller requests that can be satisfied in under two minutes.
2. Include some sort of no-op operation in your response format, and have the ASMX service periodically send a no-op if the full response isn't ready yet.  This will keep the connection alive while the long computation continues.  However, this will require a pretty deep understanding of all the buffering between the client and the ASMX service, because you won't want the no-op operation to buffer, as you are specifically using it to keep the connection open.  This can be difficult to understand.
3. Turn the single request/response into two request/response pairs, one for 'start' and one for 'check'.  The 'start' API starts the calculation, and returns some sort of ID, which the client can use to invoke the 'check' API to see if the calculation is complete, and fetch the result.

Comment: If it's possible to do so, it would also be a salient objective to see if the long running calculation can be broken into precompile and on request. If anything takes four minutes of server time to calculate, it's inefficient somehow, even if it's just running during peak request (and electricity rate) periods.

Comment: Thanks Michael Donohue for your reply. Huge calculation is doing some insurance premium calculation depending upon some risks but it is working fine as it is working efficiently while the app is being run on web-browser. in this app also when i see the response of the app in debug mode in netbeans7 i am getting response but the phone app is getting disconnected from the tomcat server after 1 min every time, before the ASMX service could provide it the result.

Comment: for some constraints it is not possible to break the operation which is taking more than normal time period to provide the result of calculation.